# Live USB - Kali Linux - Mac (Probind EDD)

Tags: linux, windows

Creé un live *USB* según la guía de instalación de los documentos de *Kali Linux*, intento iniciar el *Live USB* desde mi *Macbook Pro 13 mid late 2012*, mantengo apretado el botón opción al iniciar y me aparece el menú de arranque.

Ahí me aparecen tres opciones: La *SSD*, *Windows* y *EFI Boot*, apreto en *Windows* porque en *EFI Boot* se queda pegado y me aparece el menú de arranque de *Kali Linux*. Una vez ahí selecciono *Live Mode* y se queda pegado en una pantalla negra que dice:

> Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)

Agradecería una solución.

Comment: Que herramienta usaste para hacer booteable el pendrive? Te recomiendo RUFUS (https://rufus.akeo.ie/)

Comment: Utiliza mac linux usb Guia: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-stick-on-your-mac/ Descarga la herramienta: https://www.sevenbits.io/mlul/#downloads , es de pago el compilado pero es open source. Saludos

Comment: Use la terminal de Mac OS X únicamente, pero esa herramienta es para windows